# TeX to html (and from there, to .mobi) for

Tags: tex4ht, htlatex, tex4ebook

I am a complete beginner at TeX, but am trying to convert [Euclid's Elements from Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/21076)'s TeX format to html so that I can then use Calibre's command-line ebook-convert to go to .mobi for reading on my Kindle. PDF, even when I change the print settings in Preview to A5 (5.83"x8.27") and then print to PDF again, is too small for me to read comfortably, and the percentage read footer at the bottom gets in the way.  For most of the following, I have renamed the TeX file to EuclidsElements1-6.tex.  I have a MacBook pro, hence the Fink usage in the following.

Things I've tried (that I can remember):

1. [tex2ebook.py](https://tex2ebook.wordpress.com) (installing all required packages but Calibre using Fink).  This didn't work fully because my ebook-convert path was broken due to my using the Calibre binary, but I found the .html output file and manually used ebook-convert to get it to .mobi.  Unfortunately, the .mobi only included about 4 pages of the book's introduction.  Possibly because of a lot of hevea and Bibtex warnings about \vfill \dotfill and \frontmatter "not found", "minipage, output may be poor", and a "Giving up command: \mbox" (should I include the copious output here?).
2. /sw/share/tex4ht/bin/mzlatex EuclidElements1-6.tex

This went well until here:

```
No file EuclidElements1-6.aux.
[1] [2] [1] [2] [3] [4]

LaTeX Warning: File `images/f000.png' not found on input line 387.

l.387 --- TeX4ht warning --- File `images/f000.png' not found ---
l.387 --- TeX4ht warning --- Cannot determine size of graphic in   images/f000.png (no BoundingBox) ---
[5] [6] [7]
---------------------------------------------------------
l.459 --- TeX4ht warning --- If not done so, the index is to be processed by 
  tex '\def\filename{{EuclidElements1-6}{idx}{4dx}{ind}} \input idxmake.4ht' 
  makeindex -o EuclidElements1-6.ind EuclidElements1-6.4dx instead of 
  makeindex -o EuclidElements1-6.ind EuclidElements1-6.idx 
On some platforms, the quotation marks ' should be 
 replaced by double quotation marks " or eliminated. 
---------------------------------------------------------  ---
[1] [2]
No file EuclidElements1-6.4tc
```

. . . and so on with the missing images and lots of other warnings.

3. htlatex EuclidElements1-6.tex

TONs of errors, starting with:

```
LaTeX Warning: File `images/f000.png' not found on input line 387.

l.387 --- TeX4ht warning --- File `images/f000.png' not found ---
l.387 --- TeX4ht warning --- Cannot determine size of graphic in images/f000.png (no BoundingBox) ---
 [4] [5] [6]
```

and so on with the images that it could never find.  Also, never ending instances of:

```
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
\Link ->\let \:attr \empty \futurelet \let:val 
                                              \HRefT:ag 
l.14915 ...lo's\index{Philo, proofs by} solution,}
```

I finally had to Ctrl-Z out of htlatex.  httex didn't even load the .sty files at the beginning, so I'd guess that's going in the wrong direction.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Welcome! In most shells, ctrl-Z pauses a process. It does not stop it.

Comment: You need to download everything at http://www.gutenberg.org/files/21076/21076-t/, including the contents of the sub-directory and make sure that the directory you work in has the `.tex` file and the `images` sub-directory, containing all the figures. I'm not saying it will work. But this will at least give it a chance. Start by compiling with `pdflatex` to PDF as that's probably what they did. If that doesn't work, fix the problems before trying tex4ht. Only try tex4ht once you know you've sorted the basic problems.

Comment: Probably http://www.gutenberg.org/files/21076/ might download everything you need, though I haven't checked.

Comment: `This didn't work fully because my ebook-convert path was broken due to my using the Calibre binary, ...`. I don't understand this, but since you seem to, shouldn't you fix this before proceeding? If by any chance you installed TeX using Fink *don't*. Undo the installation and install MacTeX. (Personally, I wouldn't trust Fink at all, but don't use it for TeX at any rate.)

Comment: you can try `tex4ebook`, which is based on `tex4ht` and can convert to `mobi` automatically. files on Project Guttenberg often need some edits before it's possible to compile them using `tex4ht`. I will be offline next week, so I can't take a look at that now, unfortunately.

Comment: @cfr Thank you!  You just answered perhaps my biggest question given all the "image not found" errors I was getting--why does it seem like it should have image files that I don't have?  I was thinking maybe the .tex format was some sort of archive kind of like .jar for java but, hey, you pointed out I was not looking in the "More files" section which I now see--I will try tex2ebook.py again using *all* the files tomorrow when I have time, or your suggestion for pdflatex (which I think I did also try before, but without the image files I of course didn't get far).

Comment: @cfr Also to answer your Calibre path question, I was seeing this:
`dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/calibre-launcher.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/bin/ebook-convert
  Reason: image not found`
Instead of the above path, I had to use the path of the Calibre binary:
`/Applications/calibre.app/Contents/MacOS/ebook-convert EuclidElements1-6.html EuclidElements1-6.mobi --language en`

Comment: @michal.h21 Thank you! I did look at tex4ebook for a long time before deciding I did not know how to install and run it on my Mac, so I just went with what was installable by Fink (tex4ht, etc.). [aside: cfr, I will look at installing MacTex instead--thanks again] But as you can see above, I did have more basic problems at first, and if including the actual images this time does not help with tex2ebook.py, I will look at tex4ebook again.

Comment: That's a fairly standard problem running software on OS X. On a GNU/Linux box, for example, the equivalent of `.dyld` files (`.so`) are stored in certain common directories and binaries share access to these libraries so each application doesn't need to install its own. `.dyld` are OS X's shared libraries, but the way many applications are installed (ones which are designed to look-and-feel like native applications), they are not shared but bundled with the binaries in binary-specific directories. This is designed to prettify things but causes a great many complications (and much bloat).

Comment: I hear ya, @cfr.  One of the things I like about OSX though is that I can still use open source software because of the ports and semi-compatibility (most of the time!), while everyone else in the house is happy because everyday things generally work and are pretty.  Anyway, I think I have found success, thanks to your tips, cfr and michal.h21!  I installed MacTeX and also downloaded all the image files as cfr suggested.  Then, I discovered that MacTeX also includes tex4ebook, so after running pdflatex on the tex file and successfully generating what appears to be a good .pdf, I ran tex4ebook.

Comment: (cont'd) Got quite a few errors and ended up just setting it to run uninterrupted, but ended up with an epub (I thought I correctly used the `-f mobi` switch to change the output format, but got a weird -mobi directory with an epub in it).  Doesn't really matter, though, because I was able to import the .epub into Calibre's GUI library and convert to .mobi from there.  I uploaded it to my kindle and it looks great so far, old-timey scanned circles and angles and all, but it's 400-some pages so can't say definitively.  michal.h21, I can send you the error log when you are back if you like.

Comment: BTW, do you guys want to create an answer that I can accept, or can I just create one myself and thank you?

Comment: OT: I really got fed up with OS X when Apple introduced a charge for the developers' tools. A nominal one at that time, but I thought it was wrong in principle. Now that they are denying users root access by default, I can only say I'm relieved not to be on their platform. However, it would sometimes be nice if certain things just worked. (Most do just work and can look as pretty as you please. But there are exceptions, for sure.)

Comment: Why don't you write an answer and make it Community Wiki? Unless @michal.h21 objects. I don't think any one person really provided the answer here, so a community answer seems right to me.

Comment: OT: yes, I do a lot of sudo when tinkering, but it works for me as I'm usually using stock software (until I, say, get the itch to convert an ancient book to kindle format).  Creating the answer now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it was important to download the `images` directory along with the .tex file from Project Gutenberg by clicking on "More Files" from the main title directory:

http://www.gutenberg.org/files/21076/

I downloaded the .zip file in that directory, and expanded/unzipped it in my working directory to get the .tex file and an `images` folder.

Next, I ran pdflatex from this working directory which contained the file and images folder, and successfully generated a .pdf file that looked pretty good when I opened it in Preview, in spite of the copious warnings it generated.

Finally, I uninstalled fink's texlive and installed MacTex instead, which includes tex4ebook.  I had to add the convoluted install path to my $PATH variable thus:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/universal-darwin/
```

Actually I put it somewhere in the middle of my path by spelling out the whole path instead of using $PATH, but I think the above should work and is more concise.  At this point, from the same working directory as above, I ran `tex4ebook -f mobi 21076-t.tex` and it too generated a slew of warnings and errors.  Finally I just set it to run uninterrupted ("R") and it eventually finished.

The output was an .epub instead of .mobi, but this was easily converted in  Calibre's GUI.  The text and old scanned images, if a tad wonky at times, look pretty good on the Kindle so far, although I haven't read carefully through the ebook to see if there are any continuity problems.  Hearty thanks to @cfr and @michal.h21!